# filter() but keep groups without value

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I am trying to condense a grouped df, pulling out only rows that contain a certain value, but that value isn't reflected in all groups. I want to find a way to pull out all rows with that value, but also make a NA or 0 row for groups not containing that value.

Ex:

```r
x1 <- c('1','1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2','2','3','3','3','3','3')
x2 <- c('a','b','c','d','e','b','c','d','e','f','a','b','d','e','f')
df <- data.frame(x1,x2)

df %>% group_by(x1) %>%
  filter(x2 =="a")
```

this returns:

```r
  x1    x2   
  <fct> <fct>
1 1     a    
2 3     a
```

but I want it to return:

```r
  x1    x2   
  <fct> <fct>
1 1     a    
2 2     NA
3 3     a
```

Obviously the real code is much more complicated, so I'm looking for the best way to keep these empty groups in a reproducible way.

PS - I would like to stay in dplyr to keep smooth in a function chain

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(x1) %>%
 slice(which.max(x2 == "a")) %>%
 mutate(x2 = replace(x2, x2 != "a", NA_complex_))

  x1    x2   
  <fct> <fct>
1 1     a    
2 2     <NA> 
3 3     a
```

If it's relevant to have multiple target values per group:

```
df %>%
 group_by(x1) %>%
 filter(x2 == "a") %>%
 bind_rows(df %>%
            group_by(x1) %>%
            filter(all(x2 != "a")) %>%
            slice(1) %>%
            mutate(x2 = replace(x2, x2 != "a", NA_complex_)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of the way Dplyr was written.
According to Hadley Wickham (the Package Creator) to maintain NA values you should declare that you want them explicitly. As he said in [this issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3196) on github, you should `filter(a == x | is.na(a))`. In your case you use the following:

```
df %>% group_by(x1) %>%
filter(x2 =="a" | is.na(x2)
```

That you'll return you this as a result:

```
  x1    x2   
 <fct> <fct>
1 1     a    
2 2     NA
3 3     a
```

In this code you're asking to R all rows in which x2 is equal to "a" and also those in which x2 is NA.

Comment: Hello, that seems promising, but did not work!

```r
df %>% group_by(x1) %>%
  filter(x2 =="a" | is.na(x2))
```
returns: 
```r
  x1    x2   
1  1     a    
2  3     a 
```

am I missing something? (sorry, I can't line break in the comments so this looks dumb, but you get the point. NA row is still missing)

Answer (score 1):

As you did not specify dplyr solutions only, here's one option with `library(data.table)`

```
setDT(df)
df[, .(x2 = x2[match('a', x2)]), x1]
#    x1   x2
# 1:  1    a
# 2:  2 <NA>
# 3:  3    a
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `complete` after the `filter` step to get the missing combinations.  By default, all the other columns will be filled with `NA` (it can be made to custom value with `fill` argument)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  filter(x2 == 'a') %>% 
  complete(x1 = unique(df$x1))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  x1    x2   
#  <fct> <fct>
#1 1     a    
#2 2     <NA> 
#3 3     a
```

---

Another option is `match`

```
df %>% 
     group_by(x1) %>% 
     summarise(x2 = x2[match('a', x2)])
```

If there are many columns, then `mutate` 'x2' with `match` and then `slice` the first row

```
df %>%
   group_by(x1) %>%
   mutate(x2 = x2[match('a', x2)]) %>%
   slice(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the base R solution using `aggregate()` like below?

```
dfout <- aggregate(x2~x1,df,function(v) ifelse("a" %in% v,"a",NA))
```

or

```
dfout <- aggregate(x2~x1,df,function(v) v[match("a", v)])
```

such that

```
> dfout
  x1   x2
1  1    a
2  2 <NA>
3  3    a
```